# How can I do blue green deployment for Celery?

Tags: python, deployment, rabbitmq, celery

I'm worrying about celery deployment.
So I'm looking for safe deployment like blue green deployment for Celery.

But is this possible for celery? 
If celery worker is killed(detached) in the middle of executing task, that task is failed maybe.  Or another worker try to catch failed task detecting celery worker is killed(detached)?

Is there someone try to deploy celery worker code safely?

Answer (score 0):

Celery can retry tasks if you want. The correct thing to do depends entirely on your requirements and on whether the operations in your task can be re-executed safely - please see the docs for [apply_async()](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/celery.app.task.html#celery.app.task.Task.apply_async) which describes the `retry` option, the [FAQ](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/faq.html#should-i-use-retry-or-acks-late) on `retry` and `acks_late`, and the relevant [settings](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/configuration.html#celery-task-publish-retry)

Comment: Even if celery task code was changed from task code prefetched, task will be executed correctly? I think I might have to message to Rabbitmq that code was changed...

Comment: you control the code deployment - it's up to you to manage this correctly.